NGINX / Lua - dynamic root folder / URI rewrite
I am running an NGINX server with Lua (via OpenResty).
I want to implement a very simple thing:

If the user accesses / serve from the folder startpage
If the user accesses any other path, for example /foo, serve from the folder /html/foo

I tried many things, nothing seems to work. I can not change the root folder by ngx.var.document_root = "/startpage" - I get an error.
Then I tried this script, but instead of an internal rewrite of the url, I get an redirect to "/startpage", so the user can see "/startpage" in the browser adress bar, which I do not want.
-- Check if the script has already been executed - without this check, this script is called recursively
if rewritten ~= true then
    rewritten = true

    -- Root ("/") was called, set correct startpage
    if ngx.var.uri == "/" then
        ngx.req.set_uri("/startpage")
    -- Otherwise, set correct path to the called resource
    else
        ngx.req.set_uri("/html"..ngx.var.uri)
    end
end

If anyone can point me to the right direction, I would be very thankful.
What is the goal exactly?
If the user calls the root /:

If the user is logged in: Serve files from /startpage/user
If the user is logged in: Serve files from /startpage/guest

Else (user calls any other URL):

Example: User calls /foo: Serve files from /html/foo
Example: User calls /foo/bar/baz: Serve files from /html/foo/bar/baz

The authentication logic is all working, so I know if the user is logged in or not. I just need to set the root folder I serve files from dynamically.

What is in the startpage folder?

@DmitryMeyer Other folders which then contain html/css/js. For example:
/startpage/foo/index.html
/startpage/bar/index.html
/html/document1/index.html
/html/document2/index.html
And so on.

So, you want to translate (url → filesystem): / → .../startpage/index.html, /foo/ → .../startpage/foo/index.html, but also /foo/ → .../html/foo/index.html. There are obviously conflicting/ambiguous locations. I'd recommend to update the question with directory structure and urls examples, otherwise it's all but impossible to figure out what you are trying to achieve.

Thanks, I updated the question and added some more information and exact example of what I try to do. In Summary: I am looking for a way to serve files from different folders on my server, in Lua.

You don't need Lua to achieve this, location directives are enough:
location = / {
    alias ./startpage/;
    try_files index.html =404;
}

location / {
    root ./html/;
}

URL → filesystem path:

/ → /startpage/index.html
/foo/ → /html/foo/index.html
/foo/img.jpg → /html/foo/img.jpg
/bar/text.txt → /html/bar/text.txt

